# When send login request user be null for @AuthenticationPrincipal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

When I try login from front-end I am getting an error. I can signup but i can't login.

**Error**:

*java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.app.auction.user.User.getName()" because "user" is null
at com.app.auction.user.UserVM.(UserVM.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
at com.app.auction.auth.AuthController.handleAuthentication(AuthController.java:21) ~[classes/:na]*

I try to send request to this api.

**AuthController**

```
@RestController
public class AuthController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/auth")
    UserVM handleAuthentication(@CurrentUser User user) {
        return new UserVM(user);
    }
}
```

**@CurrentUser**

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})/
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@AuthenticationPrincipal  
public @interface CurrentUser {

}
```

**UserVM**

```
package com.app.auction.user;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class UserVM {
    
    private String name;
    
    private String username;
    
    private String email;
    
    private String image;
    
    public UserVM(User user) {
        this.name = user.getName();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.username=user.getUsername();
        this.image=user.getImage();
    }
}
```

**UserWithoutRole**

```
@Data
public class UserWithoutRole {
    
    @NotNull(message="Name can not be null")
    @Size(min = 2, max=50, message = "Name must be more than 2 letters ")
    private String name;
    

    @NotNull(message="Username can not be null")
    @UniqueUsername
    @Size(min=1,max=100  )
    private String username;
    
    @NotNull(message="Email can not be null")
    private String email;
    
    
    @NotNull(message="Password can not be null")
    @Size(min = 4, max=16 , message = "Password must be a minimum of 4 characters and a maximum of 16 characters. ")
    private String password;

    private String image;
    
}
```

**User**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User  implements UserDetails{
    
    

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2725432351214985546L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private long id;
    
    private String name;
    

    private String username;
    
    private String email;
    
    
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;
    
    
    private String image;

    public User() {
        
    }
    public User(UserWithoutRole user) {
        this.name = user.getName();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.username=user.getUsername();
        this.image=user.getImage();
    }
    
    

   @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<Role> roles = getRoles();
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
         
        for (Role role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
         
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }


    
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    UserAuthService userAuthService;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.httpBasic(); 
        
        http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthEntryPoint());

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/auth").authenticated()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        
        
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userAuthService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class UserAuthService implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username); //my user implements UserDetails it can return
     if(user != null && user.isEnabled()){
        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
    }else {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    }
}

private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles) {
    return roles.stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(User user, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collection) {
      return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
        user.getPassword(), collection);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. I could not get @CurrentUser even though User implements UserDetails. I got the authentication as a parameter and I converted to my User class.

```
@PostMapping("/auth")
UserVM handleAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {//@CurrentUser User user
    User user=userService.getByUsername(authentication.getName());
    return new UserVM(user);
}
```